# D3. How do I set the extent for a d3.svg.brush when using an ordinal scale?

Tags: d3.js

I am experimenting with `d3.svg.brush()` and I am hung up on how to set the brush extent when the scale it is based on is ordinal.

My data is a .tsv file:

```
letter  frequency
A   .08167
B   .01492
C   .02780
D   .04253
E   .12702
F   .02288
G   .02022
H   .06094
I   .06973
J   .00153
K   .00747
L   .04025
M   .02517
N   .06749
O   .07507
P   .01929
Q   .00098
R   .05987
S   .06333
T   .09056
U   .02758
V   .01037
W   .02465
X   .00150
Y   .01971
Z   .00074
```

I create an xScale:

```
xValue = function(d) {
    return d.letter;
};

xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
```

I now create and position the brush:

```
brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(xScale)
    .extent([????, ????)])
    .on("brush", brushed);
```

I want to use an `extent` for the brush that is a subset of the `xScale`'s extent. How do I say that in d3 code?

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349509)?

Comment: Whoa. Thanks for the tip. Go ahead and make you comment an answer.

Comment: Lars, I took a look but it does not actually address my key misunderstanding: how to specify an extent for a d3 brush. For context I am using Mike Bostock's Brush Snapping II as a guide: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232620. I want to do exactly the same but my ordinals are strings rather then Dates. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the extent with the ordinal values you have?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do I am just fuzzy on how to specify a subset of the range extent. So, for example, if my ordinals are a-z - d.letter ranges from a to z - how to I specify, say, an initial brush coverage of a single latter, say, for example the letter N.

Comment: `["n", "n"]`? That wouldn't show up at all though obviously.

Comment: Right, right. So, ["b", "e"] or whatever. I see. so - obviously now - just use the values from the range. Thanks so much Lars.